# Are the sources added to a library via the add_library command PUBLIC or PRIVATE?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to add some more structure to my CMake project. One step of this process is to move source additions to the `CMakeLists.txt`s in a few subdirectories, whereas they are currently added during target creation via [`add_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html). Unlike `add_library`, however, [`target_sources`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html) gives you the choice between `PUBLIC`, `INFERFACE`, and `PRIVATE`. The sources added by `add_library` obviously aren't interfaces, but I'm unsure if they are `PUBLIC` or `PRIVATE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CMake command `add_library` interprets its immediate sources as `PRIVATE`: the sources belongs only to the created library target and aren't propagated to a target linked with that library.

In general, non-PRIVATE sources have a very limited usage. If two or more targets are linked together and share a source file, then linker usually reports "multiple definitions" error about symbols defined in that file.